# How to dim link text/image after it has been clicked?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm designing a mobile app with angularjs and ionic framework. Perceived responsiveness is important, so I thought to implement a feature which would dim the item clicked. So: item opacity 1 -> user clicks on image -> set item opacity to for example 0.5 -> redirect user to the href address.

How should this be implemented the angular/ionic framework -way?

Here is a snippet that somewhat works, but imposes delay of 50 milliseconds. Also, preventDefault() and window.location.href are not probably the best ones to use (didn't get $location to work). Can angular-animations/css be used for the same effect? Can it be somehow imposed for all links, so that no separate animate-click attribute would be needed.

```
<a animate-click href="someaddress"><img src="somesrc"></a>
```

And the directive

```
app.directive('animateClick', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var clickingCallback = function(elem) {
      elem.preventDefault();
      element.css('opacity', 0.5);
      setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = elem.target.href
      }, 50);
      return;
    };
    element.bind('click', clickingCallback);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive to handle this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="dimMe = true" ng-class="{dimmed: dimMe}" ng-disabled="dimMe">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></a>
```

and then in your CSS:

```
.dimmed{ opactiy: 0.5; }
```

So when you click this link, it will set dimMe to true, which will add the class dimmed, and disable the link

Added a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg3b9/1/)

Comment: A directive or global is preferred since the functionality should be in most of the links in the app. I tried that code snipped, didn't work (either in a or img). Does the browser skip opacity setting? "We're moving to another page anyway, lets skip all other ui modification stuff"

Comment: I updated this logic, which you could then move into a directive if this functionality would be used extensively.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working, but dim effect is visible ~50% of cases. Same when using Chrome, or Android webView.

Comment: I just finished updating the fiddle with a directive implementation... if opacity isn't working, please look into other browser specifics, like -   filter: alpha(opacity=50);